# Python: FIFO with limited depth - optimisation question and review

Tags: python, fifo, ordereddictionary

Again, I am new to python. I need a FIFO with a limited depth.
F.e the depth is 5000, so after 5000 and more added items the first one's should be deleted to keep its depth is 5000. Some times I need to read 'the first' one and sometimes read the 'last one'. If I read the first one then it should be removed.

```
# class
class DictionaryDeque:
from collections import OrderedDict

def __init__(self, dequeDict=10):
    self._stack = OrderedDict()
    self._range = dictRange
    self.setRange(dictRange)
    self._len = 0

def len(self):
    self._len = len(self._stack)
    return self._len

def getRange(self):
    return self._range

def setRange(self, range):
    self._range = range
    # change the dict range if the dict has more items
    self.do_pop()

def add(self, key, value):
    self._stack[key] = value
    self.len()
    self.do_pop()

def stack(self):
    if self._len > 0:
        self.do_pop()
        return self._stack
    else:
        return ""

def last(self):
    self.do_pop()
    if self._len > 0:
        return list(self._stack)[-1]
    else:
        return list(self._stack)[0]

def first(self):
    self.do_pop()
    return list(self._stack)[0]

def do_pop(self):
    while self.len() > self._range:
        self._stack.popitem(last=False)
    self.len()

# end of class

dequeDict = DictionaryDeque(30)

for i in range (0, 40):
   now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
   dequeDict.add(now, i)



dequeDict.setRange(10)
print(dequeDict.len())
print(dequeDict.last())
print(dequeDict.first())
print(dequeDict.stack())
```

I have to implement the 'first read and remove' and some more functions, but before I start with that, I would love to know if this the/a way to go, or should there be something better?

Is there a way to avoid the list part in

```
list(self._stack)[0]
```

?

BTW, what is a good name for this class? < class name changed

Thank you

Comment: Calling it a `FIFOStack` is an oxymoron. Stacks are FILO. What you're describing sounds like a queue. There already exist various queue implementations in the `queue` standard library module, which also let you set a maximum size. *EDIT* it sounds like you want a `collections.deque` actually.

Comment: FIFOStack was wrong, I know, but didn't get the right word in my mind.collections.deque that is it. Thank you, except there shouldn't be a way to add something in front. And the deque that I found doesn't remove the first item when read.